# Get path to My Documents

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

From Visual C++, how do I get the path to the current user's My Documents folder?

**Edit:**

I have this:

```
TCHAR my_documents[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, my_documents);
```

However, `result` is coming back with a value of `E_INVALIDARG`. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on how old of a system you need compatibility with. For old systems, there's [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(VS.85).aspx).  For somewhat newer systems, there's [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx). Starting with Vista, there's [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx).

Here's some demo code that works, at least on my machine:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

int main() { 
    CHAR my_documents[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, my_documents);

    if (result != S_OK)
        std::cout << "Error: " << result << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Path: " << my_documents << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried SHGetFolderPath, and something's not quite working - would you mind having a look at my edit in the question?

Comment: This seems to be a python builtin now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227590/finding-the-users-my-documents-path

Comment: FYI, straight from ShlObj.h: #define CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS CSIDL_PERSONAL // Personal was just a silly name for My Documents

Answer (score 9):

Use [the `SHGetFolderPath` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) and request `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS`.

Comment: i think that link not correct, fix: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that, and something's not quite working - would you mind having a look at my edit in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio 2017 with an MFC application under Windows 10 I am using the following code snippet with [SHGetKnownFolderPath function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx) to get the current user's Documents folder:

```
#include <string>     // include file for C++ native strings

//  . . .  other code.

PWSTR   ppszPath;    // variable to receive the path memory block pointer.

HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &ppszPath);

std::wstring myPath;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    myPath = ppszPath;      // make a local copy of the path
}

CoTaskMemFree(ppszPath);    // free up the path memory block
```

Note that the documentation has this to say about the path variable usage and the path returned:

> ppszPath [out]
>
> Type: PWSTR*
>
> When this method returns, contains the address of a pointer to a
>   null-terminated Unicode string that specifies the path of the known
>   folder. The calling process is responsible for freeing this resource
>   once it is no longer needed by calling `CoTaskMemFree`. The returned
>   path does not include a trailing backslash. For example, "C:\Users" is
>   returned rather than "C:\Users\".

For a list of the `FOLDERID_` arguments possible see the MSDN article [KNOWN_FOLDER_FLAG enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378447(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Note that CSIDL_PERSONAL will not return the desired folder if the user has changed the default save folder in the Win7 Documents library. To get the right folder, you need to use `SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder` to obtain the `IShellLibrary` for the Documents library, use `IShellLibrary::GetDefaultSaveFolder` to get the `IShellItem` for the library's default save folder, and finally use `IShellItem::GetDisplayName` to get the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string GetMyDocumentsFolderPath()
{
    wchar_t Folder[1024];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, 0, 0, Folder);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        char str[1024];
        wcstombs(str, Folder, 1023);
        return str;
    }
    else return "";
}

cout<<GetMyDocumentsFolderPath()<<endl;
```

how about this solution? Its working fine for me.

Comment: It seems that you are not using the csidl argument. If I understood well, it should probably be put as the second argument of SHGetFolderPathW() instead of CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS.