# How do you get the exact path to "My Documents"?

Tags: python, windows

In C++ it's not too hard to get the full pathname to the folder that the shell calls "My Documents" in Windows XP and Windows 7 and "Documents" in Vista; see [Get path to My Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414828/get-path-to-my-documents)

Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: I don't know much about windows, but isn't `os.environ['HOMEPATH']` usually defined on windows systems?

Comment: @Joe, on my system `os.environ['HOMEPATH']` returns `'\\'`.

Comment: @Mark - Ah, my apologies... It seemed to work on the couple of XP machines that I have access to, and I vaguely recalled it being standard... I guess not!

Comment: +1 for not wanting to use a hard-coded path to the "My Documents" folder.

Comment: On my XP machine it's `'\\Documents and Settings\\Nick'`, almost identical to `USERPROFILE` which adds the drive letter.

Comment: @ In silico - there is no way to get a hard coded path, every user on every machine has a variation for their username

Comment: Irritatingly, Windows does not include the environment variable for this. Attempting to use HOMEPATH or USERPROFILE will burn you, as said directory is not guaranteed to exist in them, either because of Localization or because the System Administrator has moved it.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: That doesn't prevent some [morons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding#My_Documents_folder_path) [from](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/28/563008.aspx) [trying](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx).

Comment: A related question that may be easier to understand and use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227590/finding-the-users-my-documents-path

Comment: @mbear except that the answer there doesn't work, it only gets you halfway there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the ctypes module to get the "My Documents" directory:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import MAX_PATH

dll = ctypes.windll.shell32
buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(MAX_PATH + 1)
if dll.SHGetSpecialFolderPathW(None, buf, 0x0005, False):
    print(buf.value)
else:
    print("Failure!")
```

Source: http://bugs.python.org/issue1763#msg62242

Comment: I'd give a +1, but using the ANSI version may be limiting on directories that use characters outside the default code page.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy, thanks I didn't notice that. I've changed my answer to use the unicode version instead.

Comment: I presume the magic constant 0x0005 is CSIDL_PERSONAL. Is the magic constant 300 documented somewhere, or is it just MAX_PATH with some arbitrary padding added?

Comment: @Mark Ransom, yes, the hard coded 300 is MAX_PATH + 40 bytes of padding.

Comment: FWIW, a `SHGetSpecialFolderPathW()` call returns True if successful, False otherwise, so that can be checked to determine if anything useful was placed in `buf.value`.

Comment: FYI: While answering a similar question, I discovered that you can avoid hard-coding the MAX_PATH by simply importing `wintypes` from the `ctypes` module: `from ctypes import wintypes`. Now rather than hard-coding the MAX_PATH as `260`, you can just access it like so: `wintypes.MAX_PATH`.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the folder code (`0x0005`), you could use the [CSIDL][1] (constant special item ID list) constants defined in `win32com.shell.shellcon`.  In this case, the code would be `win32com.shell.shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL`.

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx