# 'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt, include, declaration

I am migrating a huge project from Qt 4.x to 5, (in fact I have asked for help several times here, I couldnt be more grateful for your help).
I am getting the next error:

> ..\marssies\userlayerswidget.cpp: In member function 'void
>   LayersModel::importFromOld()':
>   ..\marssies\userlayerswidget.cpp:1736:60: error: **'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT'
>   was not declared in this scope**

It doesnt make too much sense, as I have the correct header included, here are all the includes:

```
#include "userlayerswidget.h"
#include "appcommon.h"
#include "messagebox.h"
#include "polyline.h"
#include "painterbar.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "polygon.h"
#include "label.h"
#include "line.h"
#include "point.h"
#include "encsymbol.h"
#include "touchswibz.h"
#include "mapmodulelist.h"
#include "offlinelayersaver.h"
#include "circle.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QtDebug>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Shlobj.h>
#endif
```

And here is the piece of code that makes use of SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT:

```
void LayersModel::importFromOld() {
TCHAR appPath[MAX_PATH];
if (!(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, appPath))) {
    //code
}
```

I have researched and everything is correct according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx 
I tried to find other people with the same problem but either the context was different or the question wasnt answered.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing more research I found an answer that was to replace SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT with a literal 0, I did it and it compiled, but I'm not sure if it will be the same (I haven't written this program, I'm just migrating it). So if anybody could give some insight it would be nice.

Source: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/200660-undeclared-variable/

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: This is totally wrong. SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT is in the 4th parameter, CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE is for the 2nd parameter. The link says to use literal 0 instead of SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT in the 4th parameter, and that is presumably what actually worked here. If you also used CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE in the 2nd parameter, you would get the wrong path back: Temporary Internet Files rather than Application Data.

Comment: @stevek_mcc you're like 4 years late but thanks. Sadly I can't remove the answer but feel free to edit it.

Comment: Thanks dasjkdj, I've now edited your answer to correct it as above. Sorry for the lateness, I'd seen the Nov 2017 edit date from after sergiol's edit.

Answer (score 4):

In `ShlObj.h` is `SHFGP_TYPE_CURRENT` defined like this:

```
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0500)

typedef enum {
    SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0,
    SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT = 1,
} SHGFP_TYPE;

#endif
```

So one can do this:

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500
#include <ShlObj.h>
```

Or another way is to directly use value `0` or `1` as parameter to `SHGetFolderPath`.