# Find desktop folder in a custom location?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

Is there a way to find the path of a user folder (desktop, downloads, etc...) if the folder was moved?

These don't lead to the correct path:

```
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
```

Also, os.environ doesn't have any other key that will lead to the new path.

[image: Moved folder]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30924555/3714940) works for me. Putting the code in a loop showed that `CSIDL_PERSONAL = 16` for `Desktop`. Although, `Downloads` didn't appear, so maybe this isn't quite the complete solution

Comment: @SiHa As I've stated in my question, os.expanduser('~') leads to a different path than the custom path I've set.

Comment: Look at the answer I've linked in my comment, this is a different solution that doesn't rely on `'~'`

Comment: Thanks. I did, but it looks ugly. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @Nir, no, you'll have to do some kind of WinAPI call. Wrap ctypes / cffi / pywin32 extension call with some function and forget about how complicated it is. Any other library would have to do exactly the same.