# python save files to user folder (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, file

I have this program in Python which should save text files to a folder inside the "My Documents" of the user. The problem is that the program doesn't know the username, or the Windows version to know the correct path. How could I get this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) says, the following code is expanded to the user's home directory on windows too..

```
homeDir = os.path.expanduser("~")
```

---

From the documentation:

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created user path derived above.

---

Also look into this for using [Win32APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3927493/227884)

Comment: @JBernardo: Its actually uses more environment-variables than that. I updated my post with the actual wordings.

Comment: this is not the correct solution, but it helps. This gives the Path to the user's home, not the user's My Documents folder

Answer (score 4):

Get from the environment variable:

```
os.environ['USERPROFILE']
```

or

```
os.environ['HOME']
```

Comment: On my Windows 10 system, it likes the 'USERPROFILE' version but doesn't like the 'HOME'  one and reports an error.  The USERPROFILE version returns "C:\Users\<myUser>"

Answer (score 2):

The [winpaths](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpaths/) package provides functions to retrieve the values you need.