# How to get full path of Documents in C/C++ on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

As far as I know, "Documents" and all other directories under home are localization related, my question is: is it possible to get full path of "Documents" in C/C++ on Linux (Ubuntu)? Didn't find it in `PATH` nor other `env`.

I'm not looking for `$HOME`, I'm looking for `${HOME}"Documents"`. For instance, it's "Documents" for English locale, but "文档" for Chinese, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path to My Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414828/get-path-to-my-documents)

Comment: `Documents` is not required to exist at all, so you need to check whether it is provided before attempting to get the path. In Linux the `$HOME` environment variable holds the user home directory which is where `Documents` would be located if it exists.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez It's not its duplicate because it's not the same OS.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I'm asking with Linux, thanks.

Comment: The `xdg-user-dir` command could be useful to know. Read its manual page with `man xdg-user-dir`. And [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) might be useful as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I updated the description, I understand it's not required to exist, so is it possible to retrieve it if it exists?

Comment: @paladin_t It will be distribution dependent but I expect most popular distros will use free-desktop-org settings as per Mike's answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the info, it's helpful

Comment: @paladin_t, yes, see the `open` function to check whether the directory exists, e.g. `int fd = open (dirname, flags, mode);` if the return is `-1` it doesn't exist, otherwise just close the fd, and you know it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, if this is based on the XDG FreeDesktop standard, then there are two files that contain the info:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.locale
```

and

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

The former contains the locale itself, while the second contains the mapping to the actual folder paths.

References:

[1] https://blogs.gnome.org/simos/2007/11/11/localisation-issues-in-home-directory-folders-xdg-user-dirs/
[2] https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/